# Covariance matrix equality

Tags: covariance, matrix

The (unbiased) sample covariance matrix

$$\mathbf{S}=\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{X}_{j}-\bar{\mathbf{X}})(\mathbf{X}_{j}-\bar{\mathbf{X}})^{T}$$
can be rewritten as

$$\mathbf{S}=\dfrac{1}{n-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}-\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{T}\mathbf{X}$$

where $$\mathbf{1}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{array}\right)_{(n\times1)}.$$

One (tedious) way of proving this is to expand out the left hand side and the right hand side of the equality, and showing that the entries of the matrices match. I've done this successfully.

My question: is there a neater / more concise way to prove such an equality?

Comment: Along the lines of $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_{j}-\bar X)(X_{j}-\bar X)^T
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (X_{j}X_{j}^T-X_{j}\bar X^T-\bar X X_{j}^T+\bar X \bar X^T)$
and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\bar X X_{j}^T=\bar X\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}^T=n\bar X\bar X^T = \frac{1}{n} X^T1 (X^T1)^T$ etc